# The significance of @ in comments

Tags: c

I have a header file. That file is filled with multi line comments. In comments there are many time some words appear with @ e.g

```
/** @that


*/
```

Now this "that" changes color from green to orange(in Keil IDE). These comments doesn't seem affecting anything. Is there any thing significant behind changing color of this text? Or this is just another thing about comments that I don't know, and it is harmless? Please note that when I remove one star behind "that", it changes color to green as well.

Comment: It's (most likely) part of a code documentation generator (looks like Doxygen). That is not part of the C language, it's an external tool

Comment: There are tools which can go through your source and extract documentation from it, including special "tags" in comments. It is very likely that what you're seeing is such a special tag that will be handled such a tool.

Comment: It looks like this question (not saying it's duplicate, though) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36192264

Comment: There are various annotation schemes using different markers in comments to provide extra structured information about the code.  The `@` will be another.  AFAICR, it works for [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/manual/docblocks.html) — though the manual shows `@` with Python but not in C as far as I can see.  (More accurately, the `/**` marks the start of a Doxygen comment block.  The `@` notation will require more research.)

Comment: Please copy a complete example, not just "@that"

Comment: @JonathanLeffler @ works for any language. The usual default is \ but @ works just as well.

Answer (score 6):

It's not by chance that you see that in a header file, since it's related to ***documentation***.

It is not part of the C language itself, like for example using `/*` for comments, but most of the times, it is used for annotating a function, or/and (as in your case) a parameter.

Example:

```
/**
 * @annotateThatFunctionAsInvokable
 * Add two integers
 *
 * @param   [in]    a    first addend
 * @param   [in]    b    second addend
 * @param   [out]   sum of 'a' and 'b'
*/
void add(int a, int b);
```

---

Note: C preprocessor pretty much [ignores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009526/are-comments-always-processed-before-the-preprocessor) the contents of a comment, thus any annotations will be taken into account by the documentation tool only.

PS: A really wide used documentation tool is [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/), which in order to understand your documentation and parse it correctly, uses these `@`.

Comment: The important thing to note is that the C preprocessor doesn't care much about what goes into a comment block. The extra annotations are of note only to the documentation tool.